# Issue with creating virtual environment on wsl2 and onedrive

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, onedrive, python-venv, rclone

I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2), and OneDrive mounted using rclone, on a Windows 10 machine.
When using WSL2 in the local directories, I can create a virtual environment for a project:

```
python -m venv myenv/
```

However, if I'm in a directory on OneDrive, and I run this command, I get an error:

```
Error: [Errno 5] Input/output error: 'lib' -> '/home/andrew/onedrive/myproject/venv/lib64'
```

If I look in the myproject directory, I can see that directory venv has been created.  However it is incomplete, in that it only has 'lib' and 'include' subdirectories.  When it is created properly (that is, in a directory not on OneDrive), it has 'lib, 'include', 'bin', 'lib64', 'share', and 'pyvenv.cfg'.

'lib64' is a symbolic link pointing to 'lib' in the normal installation.  In the error message above, it seems that lib is actually pointing to lib64, so I suppose this is the input/output error?

Is there a way to get venv to work on OneDrive directories when mounted via rclone and using WSL2?

Comment: How is OneDrive mounted?  Is it somehow mounted directly in the home directory?  Or is that a symbolic link to another location where it is mounted?

Comment: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/how-to-mount-onedrive-in-linux-using.html   I followed the procedure at this link to mount it using an open source tool called 'rclone'.  I imagine MSFT will make a more seamless integration with one drive eventually, but for now this is how it is mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hunch is that something in the way Rclone works is causing your issue.  It purports to be "inspired by `rsync`", which means that it isn't really "mounting", but is "syncing" the cloud storage.

I did a quick install of `rclone` in a new WSL instance, and I'm seeing the same "Input/Output error" that you experienced.

I'm guessing that you would see the same problem even if under a "full" Linux installation.  In other words, I doubt this has anything to do with the interaction between WSl and `rclone`.  It's probably more about the interaction between Python's `venv` module and `rclone`.  I don't know for sure, but I have my doubts that `rclone` is designed for "live" usage.  It's more for being able to access (and write) files on cloud-storage providers from Linux.

The good news is that there's likely an alternative.  Windows automatically makes your OneDrive folder available in `%userprofile%\OneDrive`.  From WSL, you can access this with:

```
cd $(powershell.exe -c 'Write-Host -NoNewLine $env:userprofile' | xargs -0 wslpath)/OneDrive
```

That's usually `/mnt/c/Users/<yourusername>/OneDrive`.

From there, `python3 -m venv myvenv/` worked correctly for me.

That said, I highly recommend against doing this in WSL2, as performance of NTFS files is abysmal.  Best to use a WSL1 instance if you really need to do it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  I got it to work as you suggested.  I suppose since you can get to OneDrive either way, I should use the 'Windows' way.

Comment: OneDrive can easily be configured to use a directory outside the userprofile. Consider using something like `cd $(powershell.exe -c 'Write-Host -NoNewLine $env:onedriveconsumer' | xargs -0 wslpath)` instead. See e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/1447461/environment-variables-for-onedrive-synchronisation-folders